# Sign CAB file in Windows Embedded Compact (Windows CE) 7.0

Tags: windows-ce, cab

Can someone please explain to me how can I sign a CAB file?
I'm trying to install the CAB file with the wceload.exe tool but it works only with signed CAB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an [MSDN section specifically for CAB signing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd252811.aspx).  The exact process depends on the certificate authority you want for it - meaning you can send it to someone like Verisign and get it signed, or you can self sign it and distribute your own certificate with it.

Comment: The link you sent is for Windows Mobile device. I need for win compact 7. It is the same process?
I'm getting the message box: "unsupported system version - The program is not compatible with the current operating system and, therefore, may not run on this device. Do you want to continue installation?"
May be you know what can I do in order not to get this message box?

Comment: Yes, the signing process is still the same.  What app are you running (and where) that you're getting that error?

Comment: I'm installing the CAB file on my device (Win compact 7).
I'm getting the error when I'm double click on the CAB file

Comment: The Max OS version in your INF file (used to generate the CAB) is probably set to something like 6.99.  Take a look there.

Comment: @janneob could you please tell me which value did you use in "Max OS Version"? Or can someone write a link of the list of the Version numbers to be used? Thanks!

Comment: @Vic: Just change it to 7.0 or 8.0

Comment: @ctacke thanks! That did work. But is there a list of the values? I found one in MSDN, but it does not include the last new OS..